# Is my data structure to blame for multiple select dropdown not working in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-options

I'm attempting to create a multi-select dropdown.

I saw that I could use the `ng-options` directive to basically compare two datasets, set any matching option to `selected`.

Here are the two collections I have:

```
// Full list of possible recipients and the different types

reference = {
  "AddressBook": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "FullName": "Angela Williams",
      "IsActive": true,
      "SendType": null,
      "Email": "awilliams@yamia.com"
    },
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "FullName": "Jerry Schmidt",
      "IsActive": true,
      "SendType": null,
      "Email": "jschmidt@cogibox.mil"
    },
    {
      "ID": 3,
      "FullName": "Judy Olson",
      "IsActive": true,
      "SendType": null,
      "Email": "jolson@buzzdog.gov"
    },
    {
      "ID": 4,
      "FullName": "Sara Griffin",
      "IsActive": true,
      "SendType": null,
      "Email": "sgriffin@yoveo.org"
    }
  ],
  "SendTypes": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "Value": "To"
    },
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "Value": "CC"
    },
    {
      "ID": 3,
      "Value": "BCC"
    }
  ]
}

// Selected recipients

currentNotification.TO = [
  {
    "Email": "awilliams@yamia.com",
    "FullName": "Angela Williams",
    "ID": 1, 
    "IsActive": true,
    "SendType": "To"
  },
  {
    "Email": "sgriffin@yoveo.org",
    "FullName": "Sara Griffin",
    "ID": 4, 
    "IsActive": true,
    "SendType": "To"
  }
]
```

What I've tried to use for my markup:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="sendType in reference.SendTypes">
  <label for="">{{sendType.Value}}:</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="" id="recipients{{sendType}}" ng-multiple="true" multiple ng-model="currentNotification[(sendType.Value).toUpperCase()]" ng-options="recipient.FullName for recipient in reference.AddressBook | orderBy: 'FullName'"></select>
</div>
```

With that markup, I end up with a .form-group for each SendType (To, CC, BCC). Within each of those, I have the proper label showing (sendType.Value). The multi-select is displayed and repeats an option for each entry in AddressBook. It also sorts correctly. **Unfortunately nothing is selected.**

Doing a bit of research on `ng-options`, it seems like maybe my `selected` collection needs to be an array of strings instead of an array of objects. Is that true?

Strangely enough, if I go in and select some recipients manually, the model updates as it should:

```
BCC = [
  { ... },
  { ... },
  { ... },
  { 
    "ID": 3,
    "FullName": "Judy Olson",
    "IsActive": true,
    "SendType": null,
    "Email": "jolson@buzzdog.gov"
  }
]
```

**Really appreciate any help on this. It's dragging me behind a deadline at the moment. If anyone would like a fiddle or something, let me know. Thanks again!**

Comment: create a demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) so your full scope can be viewed

Comment: please create plunker/fiddle

Comment: Creating a Plunker, just a few moments. :)

Comment: Ok, I've setup a new Plunker for this: http://plnkr.co/edit/oNiRSQfJjcbolAmRvSnV?p=preview  
I apologize about the data though. I really don't know what I'm doing and don't know how to switch it over from a Factory to stubbed out data. I've saved off the different collections coming in through the Factory to separate json files. `reference.json` and `list.json` come back via the `list` service, `detail.json` comes back via the `detail` service. Again, if you need any clarification on anything, please let me know. I really appreciate all the help :).

Comment: I've adde the _Detail.htm directive to the Plunker as well, sorry about that :(. http://plnkr.co/edit/oNiRSQfJjcbolAmRvSnV?p=preview